# Add a calendar with marked events on a website

Tags: html

I want to add a calendar to my website and mark my events on it, using html5
like the example below.
what I found on the net is this code:

```
<iframe id='cv_if5' src='http://cdn.instantcal.com/cvir.html?id=cv_nav5&file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.instantcal.com%2Ftest.ics&theme=XGY&ccolor=%23ffffc0&dims=1&gtype=cv_monthgrid&gcloseable=0&gnavigable=1&gperiod=month&itype=cv_simpleevent' allowTransparency=true scrolling='no' frameborder=0 height=600 width=800></iframe>
```

but how to generate a file contain my events? I have tried to generate an ics file using outlook but it didn't work!

The example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use an existing API. Something like google calendars. There is a very large amount of code behind what you are trying to do and as a web developer im lazy when it comes to writing code so I just use what is already out there, instead of reinventing the wheel.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think that to use google calendar the user should be loged into gmail? or I am not thinking well :p

Comment: Apologies about the late response! - As standard this is correct but if you set the calendar to be public within the basic settings menu, everyone can see your calendar, a nice simple solution :)

Comment: I embedded google calender code  in my website thank you very much :)

Comment: Ah good good - I'm pleased it's worked for you, if you have any more questions please don't hesitate to ask :)